# Rails has_and_belongs_to_many always inserts into database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord, has-and-belongs-to-many

Here is my problem:

```
class Facility < ActiveRecord::Base
...
has_and_belongs_to_many :languages, :autosave => false, :join_table => 'facilities_languages'
... 
end
```

When I do something like this:

```
facility = Facility.find(1)
language = Language.find(1)
facility.languages << language
```

Rails always do the SQL request:

```
"INSERT INTO `facilities_languages` (`language_id`,`facility_id`) VALUES (1, 1)"
```

Is there a way to avoid database requests unless I call  'facility.save' ?

Apparently, :autosave option here does something else.

Comment: what are you trying to do here with the line `facility.languages << language
` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Problem is that you use `has_and_belongs_to_many` which isnt based on a `Model` so you cant access it as an Object. You could create a `Model` that is doing the associations and then you could create new objects of this association model. e.g.:

```
rails g scaffold JoinClass faculty_id:integer language_id:integer
```

In the Model

```
class JoinClass < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :faculty
     belongs_to :language
end
```

In the other models:

Faculty

```
class Faculty < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :join_classes
     has_many :languages, :though => :join_classes
end
```

Language

```
class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :join_classes
     has_many :faculties, :through => :join_classes
end
```

Then you would be able to add associations by creating association objects which arent saved automaticly. For example you have a `String` containing ids that contains the ids of the language objects which should be associated called `language_ids` in the `FacultyController`:

```
language_ids.split(",").each do |language_id|
    JoinClass.create(:faculty_id => @faculty.id, :language_id => language_id)
end
```

Of cause this code should be conditioned and positioned after the save of faculty.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the shovel operator << Rails automatically saves the associated object.

From the documentation
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html

> collection<<(object, …)
>
> Adds one or more objects to the collection by
> creating associations in the join table (collection.push and
> collection.concat are aliases to this method). Note that this
> operation instantly fires update sql without waiting for the save or
> update call on the parent object.

Comment: It also happens if I use = or += instead. 

facility.languages = [Language.find(3)]

>>DELETE FROM `facilities_languages` WHERE `facilities_languages`.`facility_id` = 1 AND `facilities_languages`.`language_id` IN (1, 2)

>>INSERT INTO `facilities_languages` (`language_id`, `facility_id`) VALUES (3, 1)

Answer (score 0):

facility.languages = [language]

Comment: Or facility.languages += [language], or any other Array operator. Tried it, it still sends database query.